# how to download Pdf to client machine

Tags: c#

I created a Location to save converted PDF from asp.net like this:

```
public string fileUploadLoc = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PDFFileLoc"];
//set from web.config eg: d:/temp/employeeData

 DirectoryInfo destination = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/" + fileUploadLoc));
 Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath("~/" + fileUploadLoc));
destination = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/" + fileUploadLoc));
destination.Create();
```

and i converted asp.net page to PDF.  How to save this converted PDF to the specified Location.? Please help me.

Comment: do you have a file or a stream that  contain the pdf? this code only generates a path not a file.

Comment: PDF Document. I will Add to pdfDocument and       i have code at the end:-                  pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;
                pdfDoc.Close();
                pdfWriter.Close();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.Write(pdfDoc);
                Response.End();

Comment: its unclear what are you trying to accomplish, after the code you added to the comment it seems you are trying to let a client to download a PDF file, am i correct?

Comment: I saved in to one location using FileStream. And i displayed in my asp page. Now i want to download that file when i click the anchor tag. (Server side).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 System.IO.FileStream file = new System.IO.FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/" + fileUploadLoc" System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
 PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, file);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this before serializing the file into the response stream:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader(
            "content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", fileName));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        //HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

        HttpContext.Current.Response.HeaderEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: Error while opening pdf : There was an error processing a page. There was a problem reading this document(109).  I saved pdf. when i opened the saved pdf and when i downloaded pdf and opened the downloaded pdf getting error. Please help me

Comment: have you solved it? if not pls let me know ill help you with it